# neo4j will_paginate gem installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, will-paginate, neo4j.rb

Running bundle install after including the gem gives me this

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    neo4j-will_paginate (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (~> 3.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.1.6) ruby depends on
      activesupport (4.1.6)
```

I am on `gem 'rails', '4.1.6'` and the app was originally created without AR and added back in later.

I have seen some other example SO but don't want to do any gemlock changes without certainy

Suggestions on troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `neo4j-will_paginate_redux`, not that gem. We rereleased under this name because we could not get access to the original on Rubygems.